# Equals returning false in c++

Tags: c++, g++, command-line-arguments

I'm fairly new to cpp and I am trying to do a project. It says that the code must take in a filename as an argument and will be run by:

```
./main -i filename
```

I have written a for-loop that will iterate through the list of arguments to find the "-i" argument so that I can determine the filename. But this line always return false:

```
argv[i] == "-i"
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string test = argv[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        if(argv[i] == "-i"){
            test = argv[i+1];
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << test;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I understand you are writing your own parser for learning purposes. Once you know how to do it and you understand the path to achieve it, have a look here. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html

Comment: use function strcmp instead of "argv[i] == "-i"", that is the way you compare two strings in C, while in your code, both sides of "==" decay to pointers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
argv[i] == "-i"
```

In the line above you compare two pointers: `char*` and `const char*`, respectively.

In other words, instead of comparing `argv[i]` and `"-i"` two pointers are compared which are pretty much unlikely to point to the same location. As a result, the check doesn't work in your case.

You can fix it in multiple ways, for example wrap `"-i"` into `std::string` to make the comparison work properly:

```
const auto arg = std::string{ "-i" };

for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    if(argv[i] == arg){
        test = argv[i+1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Starting with *C++17* you might also use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

```
const std::string_view sv{ "-i" };

for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    if(argv[i] == sv){
        test = argv[i+1];
        break;
    }
}
```

which is a preferable way as it avoids a `std::string` creation.

Comment: You really ought to point out the out-of-bounds error if the code is called without a filename following the `-i`.  Probably the best way is to test against `argc-1`.

Comment: It'a also a good idea to start with index 1 as 0 is used for the program name.

Comment: `It compares two pointers so the result is always false.`: not true. Pointer comparison is well defined. Comparison between pointers pointing to the same address is a reasonable operation, which is quite common. The chances of the comparison between a `char*` literal and a member of `argv` being equal is pretty much zero, but still technically a legal result. It's a bit nitpicky, but this is SO `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Cyclic3 it is not nitpicky, it is totally correct :) But for me it is sometimes unclear how detailed the answer should be. Probably, I need to edit the answer and provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Edgar great! Glad I could help!

Comment: @Cyclic3 My brief searching only turned up results for C, but in C, it is valid to modify the strings in `argv`. That means that the pointers in `argv` must not be the same as a pointer to any character literal, so the comparison is required to be false.

Comment: Let's get a boatload more appreciation for what @MartinBonner said. Yikes! This code is a timebomb just waiting to go off. *Edit*: Hmm, I stand [somewhat corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607440/equals-returning-false-in-c#comment92161154_52607497), but it's still (a) totally pointless to check `argv[argc]`, (b) very dangerous if you don't expect it to be the `NULL` that it always will - which OP didn't, (c) totally pointless, and (d) a very dangerous habit to form if you start un/consciously thinking that `array[actual_size]` is a valid thing to inspect in any array.

Comment: @Justin Yeah, in this context, comparing these two pointers is _always_ false on any sane system. One is a static pointer to a read-only memory address owned by the process, the other is a variable pointer created and owned by the kernel. Of course, a really esoteric single-user single-process kernel might notice their string contents are the same and reuse the address, but I don't know of any such systems.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY My point is that an esoteric kernel *cannot* do that. It would be incorrect, because if it could do that, then modifying a string inside `argv` would modify the string literal, which cannot happen

Comment: If you’re using C++17, why not use a string literal instead of declaring a completely unnecessary constant? `if( argv[i] == "-i"sv) …`.

Comment: @Justin It could perform static analysis or allow compilers to generate different code when `argv` is (supposed to be) read-only. _writing_ to a pointer pointing to read-only data (like a string literal) is UB, but _storing_ a literal string as a `char *` is completely valid (although generally a bad idea). I don't know why anyone would create a kernel like this, but the C standard allows such foolery, so you can't say _for certain_ that an element in argv will never be equal to any string literal.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right! In either case, having the `const` outside the one expression in which it is needed is wrong in terms of proper scoping. It might seem to make sense for types that took lots of characters/lines to construct, but these aren't examples of that, even if we eschew literals and just call the constructor - and even if they were, I would argue that indicates a function is needed instead, then we would just call `if ( foo == make_some_complicated_bar() )`.

Answer (score 18):

You cannot compare pointers to `char` to string literals (`char const*`) using `==`. Use `std::strcmp()` (`<cstring>`) or construct a `std::string` (`<string>`) from it to make it comparable to a `char*` using `==`.

Comment: Simplest fix to `i` out of range is to use `i < argc-1` as the limit

Comment: or use `std::string_view` (C++17).

Comment: Note that `argv[argc]` is defined by the standard to always be valid and null, so it that code is well defined, it just might not be what you expect.

Comment: @JonathanCallen i'd quote that for truth.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string test;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){        
        cout << "\n" << argv[i] << endl;
        if((string)argv[i] == "-i"){
            test = argv[i + 1];
            cout << "test= " << test << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << test << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a good answer, explain what you changed & why it solves the Q. It's unclear what this has, beyond what others already said. I'd also (A) not advise C-style casts & (B) take a **serious** look at where you index to `argv[i + 1]`. What's going to happen if the `-i` is the final argument & you haven't bothered checking whether there is one after it you can index to? Nothing good - just undefined behaviour (i.e. a crash if OP is *lucky*, and a poisoned program). *Edit*: OK, [not quite, but still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607440/equals-returning-false-in-c#comment92164743_52607493)