# Comparing string pushed from C function in Lua fails unless copied to new string

Tags: c++, c, lua

I'm working on a program that creates a Lua 5.1 environment in an SDL window written with a mix of C and C++. I've set up an event system that queues SDL events so that Lua can pop events off the queue. One of the events is sent when a printable character is typed. When the event is detected it pushes the string into a new `lua_State`, queues it in an `std::queue`, and once it's pulled the values in the `lua_State` get copied into the main coroutine state, where they're then returned by `coroutine.yield`. But when I compare the string with a constant on the Lua side (ex: `ev[2] == "q"`), the comparison results in false. If I copy the value to a new string and compare that (ex: `"" .. ev[2] == "q"`), the comparison results in true.

I've tried using multiple ways of pushing the string (since SDL provides a UTF-8 string instead of an ASCII character), including:

- `lua_pushstring(L, e.text.text)`
  to insert the entire string
- `lua_pushlstring(L, e.text.text, 1)`
  to insert the first character
- `char tmp[2]; tmp[0] = e.text.text[0]; tmp[1] = 0; lua_pushstring(L, tmp)`
  to copy the string and insert that

but none of these fixed the issue.

Here's the basic structure in my C++ code:

```cpp
const char * termGetEvent(lua_State *L) {
    SDL_Event e;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) return "die";
        else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && keymap.find(e.key.keysym.scancode) != keymap.end()) {
            lua_pushinteger(L, keymap.at(e.key.keysym.scancode));
            lua_pushboolean(L, false);
            return "key";
        } else if (e.type == SDL_KEYUP && keymap.find(e.key.keysym.scancode) != keymap.end()) {
            lua_pushinteger(L, keymap.at(e.key.keysym.scancode));
            return "key_up";
        } else if (e.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT) { // this is the section producing errors
            char tmp[2];
            tmp[0] = e.text.text[0];
            tmp[1] = 0;
            lua_pushstring(L, tmp);
            return "char";
        } else if (e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
            lua_pushinteger(L, buttonConvert(e.button.button));
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertX(e.button.x));
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertY(e.button.y));
            return "mouse_click";
        } else if (e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP) {
            lua_pushinteger(L, buttonConvert(e.button.button));
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertX(e.button.x));
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertY(e.button.y));
            return "mouse_up";
        } else if (e.type == SDL_MOUSEWHEEL) {
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            term->getMouse(&x, &y);
            lua_pushinteger(L, e.button.y);
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertX(x));
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertY(y));
            return "mouse_scroll";
        } else if (e.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && e.motion.state) {
            lua_pushinteger(L, buttonConvert2(e.motion.state));
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertX(e.motion.x));
            lua_pushinteger(L, convertY(e.motion.y));
            return "mouse_drag";
        } else if (e.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED) {
            term->resize();
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

std::queue<std::pair<const char *, lua_State*> > eventQueue;

int getNextEvent(lua_State *L, const char * filter) {
    std::pair<const char *, lua_State*> ev;
    do {
        while (eventQueue.size() == 0) {
            lua_State *param = luaL_newstate();
            if (!lua_checkstack(param, 4)) printf("Could not allocate event\n");
            const char * name = termGetEvent(param);
            if (name != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(name, "die") == 0) running = 0;
                eventQueue.push(std::make_pair(name, param));
            } else if (param) {
                lua_pushnil(param);
                lua_close(param); 
                param = NULL;
            }
        }
        ev = eventQueue.front();
        eventQueue.pop();
    } while (strlen(filter) > 0 && strcmp(std::get<0>(ev), filter) != 0);
    // Copy the next event in
    lua_State *param = std::get<1>(ev);
    int count = lua_gettop(param);
    if (!lua_checkstack(L, count + 1)) printf("Could not allocate\n");
    lua_pushstring(L, std::get<0>(ev));
    lua_xmove(param, L, count);
    //lua_close(param);
    return count + 1;
}

lua_State *L;

int main() {
    int status, result, i;
    double sum;
    lua_State *coro;
start:
    /*
     * All Lua contexts are held in this structure. We work with it almost
     * all the time.
     */
    L = luaL_newstate();

    coro = lua_newthread(L);

    luaL_openlibs(coro); /* Load Lua libraries */
    termInit(); // initializes SDL

    /* Load the file containing the script we are going to run */
    status = luaL_loadfile(coro, bios_path);
    if (status) {
        /* If something went wrong, error message is at the top of */
        /* the stack */
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load file: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
    }
    tid = createThread(&termRenderLoop); // stops when running != 1

    /* Ask Lua to run our little script */
    status = LUA_YIELD;
    int narg = 0;
    while (status == LUA_YIELD && running == 1) {
        status = lua_resume(coro, narg);
        if (status == LUA_YIELD) {
            if (lua_isstring(coro, -1)) narg = getNextEvent(coro, lua_tostring(coro, -1));
            else narg = getNextEvent(coro, "");
        } else if (status != 0) {
            running = 0;
            joinThread(tid);
            //usleep(5000000);
            termClose();
            printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(coro, -1));
            lua_close(L);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    joinThread(tid);
    termClose();
    lua_close(L);   /* Cya, Lua */

    if (running == 2) {
        //usleep(1000000);
        goto start;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the Lua script I'm using to test:

```lua
while true do
    local ev = {coroutine.yield()}
    print(table.unpack(ev)) -- provided by previous scripts
    if ev[1] == "char" then 
        print("\"" .. ev[2] .. "\"") -- prints "q" if 'q' was pressed
        assert(ev[2] == "q") -- false, even if 'q' was pressed
        assert(string.len(ev[2]) == 1) -- true
        assert(#ev[2] == 1) -- true
        assert(string.len(string.sub(ev[2], 2, 2)) == 0) -- true
        assert(string.sub(ev[2], 1, 1) == ev[2]) -- false
        assert("" .. ev[2] == "q") -- true if 'q' was pressed
    end
    if ev[1] == "char" and string.sub(ev[2], 1, 1) == "q" then break end
end
```

I expect all of the `assert`s in the script to result in true (assuming 'q' was pressed), but some of them result in false. I had to adjust the statement with the break in it to use only the first character. Why is the string not being compared correctly?

EDIT: I'm not trying to compare the strings on the C++ side, but on the Lua side. I handle string comparisons properly in the C code (strcmp).

Comment: 1) What does `print(type(ev[2]))` print?  2) You should create `param` with `lua_newthread` instead of `luaL_newstate`, otherwise you're not allowed to use `lua_xmove`

Comment: You can't compare character arrays with `==`, it just compares the pointers so will always return false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equals returning false in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607440/equals-returning-false-in-c)

Comment: @AlanBirtles - OP compares strings in Lua script, not in C.  Lua has different string semantics.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff 1) `type(ev[2]) == "string"`. 2) I've replaced `luaL_newstate` with `lua_newthread`, but now I get a segmentation fault on `lua_close`, at `luaC_separateudata + 70`. Any way to fix that? (I suspect the string problem was caused by `luaL_newstate`.)

Answer (score 1):

After following Egor Skriptunoff's suggestion to replace `luaL_newstate` with `lua_newthread`, as well as replacing the `lua_close` calls with `lua_pop`, I was able to fix the problem. [This post](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-03/msg00709.html) on the lua-users mailing list says you can't close a new thread:

> Graham Wakefield wrote:
>
> > Hi,
> >
> > I'm having some hard to understand behavior; I create new threads using lua_newthread, and lua_resume them periodically from C++. However, I may wish to at some point terminate a thread before it has completed; I tried calling lua_close() on the thread's lua_State,
>
> You can't call lua_close() on a thread; only on the main state.

which ended up causing a segmentation fault. Since I was getting excessive memory use otherwise, I ended up replacing `lua_close` with `lua_pop` because the state is pushed onto the main stack. After applying these fixes I no longer got any segfaults and the memory usage stays constant.